# Background trouble in Iphone4 design

Tags: iphone, jquery-mobile, mobile, mobile-safari

I have a problem with layout iPhone web page , My background image does not fit on view of  safari (in iPhone4), my  background image size : `w:480 px / h:720px`.

my body css code  :

```
body
{
height:100%;
margin:0px;
background-image:url(../images/bg.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}
```

actually , i really don't know what should background resolution for retina display and normal 3g display ... and how to adjust them ...

If someone can help me , I will be glad...

Comment: Well for starters a standard (3G & GS) screen is 480x320.  Retina is double so 960x640

Comment: If i make background image size 960X640, in 3g image will wont work properly ? How can i do it without seperate css files and put if condition for which iPhone model that user have ?

Comment: http://lineandpixel.com/blog/ios-web-app-icons-and-startup-images and 
https://gist.github.com/2222823 might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi please use this code instead of your body:

```
body{
font-size:100%;
background:url(../images/bg.png) no-repeat center top;
background-size:100% auto;
margin:0 auto;
}
```